# Window which points to the system tray

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.0

Is it possible to create a Window which "points" to the system tray icon which was clicked to invoke it? I don't know what the arrow is called so I am attaching a picture to make myself clearer. WPF does not support notification icons so the system tray icon is created using `System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon`.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: rather than using windows forms helpers, try to use http://www.hardcodet.net/projects/wpf-notifyicon The default bubble popup in tutorial 5 shows a bubble with an arrow. however if you want it customized, your going to have to calculate the position and then toggle arrow visibility in your custom popup window. It at-least is a wpf solution than a windows forms one.

Comment: Notification icons are not windows.  The point of using them is that the user doesn't need an arrow to find them back, he already knows where to look.  And how to hide them if they are annoying.  Being intrusive like this invariably gets your uninstaller to be the most important asset of your program.  Not that this is possible in any documented way.